# is there a single permission type to access all data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

Recently, I have noticed applications requesting permission for "all" data rather than listing multiple items when I authorize the app (ie - manage_pages, user_photos, etc).

Does anyone know what permission type requests access for all data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no permission for all data, you are likely just talking about the first page of the dialog?